# Timeout connection quartz job

Tags: java, mysql, quartz-scheduler

I have lot of simple jobs run in background of my application on specific time.

I am getting below exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 86,399,991 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 86,399,991 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor225.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3743)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2506)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4842)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.setAutoCommit(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:98)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:66)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy189.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:799)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3796)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retryExecuteInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3754)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggeredJobComplete(JobStoreSupport.java:3051)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobStoreJobComplete(QuartzScheduler.java:1804)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:269)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Write failed)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3725)
    ... 16 common frames omitted

2017-12-06 04:55:00.095  WARN 12080 --- [eduler_Worker-3] c.m.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection     : [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
2017-12-06 04:55:00.095  WARN 12080 --- [eduler_Worker-3] c.m.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection     : [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!

java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:436)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:3869)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setString(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:963)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.deleteFiredTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:2912)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggeredJobComplete(JobStoreSupport.java:3128)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$45.executeVoid(JobStoreSupport.java:3055)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3715)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3713)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3799)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retryExecuteInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3754)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggeredJobComplete(JobStoreSupport.java:3051)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobStoreJobComplete(QuartzScheduler.java:1804)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:269)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

2017-12-06 04:55:00.095  INFO 12080 --- [eduler_Worker-3] c.m.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache    : Problem with checked-in Statement, discarding.

java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:436)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.clearParameters(PreparedStatement.java:1025)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.refreshStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:604)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.checkinStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:236)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.checkinStatement(NewPooledConnection.java:239)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.close(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1807)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.closeStatement(StdJDBCDelegate.java:3287)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.deleteFiredTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:2916)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggeredJobComplete(JobStoreSupport.java:3128)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$45.executeVoid(JobStoreSupport.java:3055)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3715)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3713)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3799)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retryExecuteInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3754)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggeredJobComplete(JobStoreSupport.java:3051)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobStoreJobComplete(QuartzScheduler.java:1804)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:269)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

2017-12-06 04:55:00.095  WARN 12080 --- [eduler_Worker-3] c.m.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection     : [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
2017-12-06 04:55:00.095  WARN 12080 --- [eduler_Worker-3] c.m.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection     : [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1246)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4564)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:855)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor646.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy189.rollback(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.rollbackConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3662)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3821)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retryExecuteInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3754)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.triggeredJobComplete(JobStoreSupport.java:3051)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobStoreJobComplete(QuartzScheduler.java:1804)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:269)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

I googled and to avoid connection out,
i added on mysql sync job which runs after 7 hours in the system but still getting this exception.

my quartz properties are as below:

```
org.quartz:
  threadPool:
    class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
    threadCount: 10
  scheduler:
    batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount: 10
    skipUpdateCheck: true
    dbFailureRetryInterval: 1000
    idleWaitTime: 5000
    instanceId: AUTO
  jobStore:
    class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
    tablePrefix: qrtz_
    driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
    dataSource: quartzDataSource
    isClustered: false
  dataSource:
    quartzDataSource:
      driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
      validateOnCheckout: true
      idleConnectionValidationSeconds: 900
```

And as i am working with spring boot my DB configuration bean properties set as

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"));
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("url"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("serverName"));
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("url", dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("url"));
        }
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("username"));
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("password"));
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(MAX_POOL_SIZE);
        config.setConnectionInitSql("SELECT 1");
        config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        if ("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
                .equals(dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts",
                    dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize",
                    dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit",
                    dataSourcePropertyResolver.getProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048"));
        }
        if (metricRegistry != null) {
            config.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        }
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
```

Is there anything wrong with my configuration?
How can i get rid of this error?
It does not occur that frequent.